# VBA: Using an array to search dynamic dataset conditions and copy based on interior.colorindex

Tags: vba, excel

[Sample data here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rFzNH.png)I have cells starting in H8 and based on array condition, it should copy and paste those cells with interior color of red (cell must be red in color and must have strings of either CCA, CUA, SEA, X etc....) The code runs fine but it does not copy anything over. Not sure whats making it not function as I intended it to.

For now I'd let to get this going. But in the future I'd like to create a dynamic range for the columns. Right now it's set for columns 8 and 9 for testing but once it start working I'll need it to any amount of columns.

Thanks for the help.

```
Sub BulkUpload()
Dim rngCell As Range
Dim lngLstRow As Long
Dim keywords() As String, maxKeywords() As String
Dim totalKeywords As Integer, i&
Dim ws As Worksheet, resultsWS As Worksheet


ActiveSheet.Name = "FileShares"    

Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1") 
Set resultsWS = Sheets("FileShares") 

totalKeywords = 6
ReDim keywords(1 To totalKeywords)
ReDim maxKeywords(1 To totalKeywords)

maxKeywords(1) = "SEA"
maxKeywords(2) = "CUA"
maxKeywords(3) = "CCA"
maxKeywords(4) = "CAA"
maxKeywords(5) = "AdA"
maxKeywords(6) = "X"


lngLstRow = ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count
Dim k&                     
For k = 8 To 9          
    With ws
        For Each rngCell In .Range(.Cells(8, k), .Cells(lngLstRow, k))
            For i = LBound(maxKeywords) To UBound(maxKeywords)
                If maxKeywords(i) = rngCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 5 Then
                resultsWS.Cells(65536, k).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Value = rngCell.EntireRow.Value
                End If
            Next i
        Next rngCell

    End With
Next k
End Sub
```

Comment: Could you post some sample data?

Comment: Did so, check original post. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Part of the problem is that you are using Interior.ColorIndex = 5. This [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840443.aspx) website has a list of the ColorIndex and 5 is blue. You mentioned you were looking for red

Comment: Thank you for providing some feedback.I added the first suggestion you commented on, no luck.  I need it to check more than column H, so suggestion 2 will not work for me. My goal is to check all columns that contain data. I was going to enter a static range but could change once VBA is working.  My goal is to copy all rows that fit the criteria.

Comment: So I looked on MSDN. Looks like ColorIndex 5 is actually blue. Maybe goto this website and see if you are picking the correct color index for the interior color you are looking for. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840443.aspx

Comment: oh jeez!! Such silly mistakes. Thank you, that worked.

Comment: Could you help me with one more thing?  I added 3 variables to make the offset to start on row 8 then copy then next value to row 9, etc... I did this as .Offset(var1+var2,0)   .... var1 = var3 + v2 - 7 where var1=6, var2=1 var3=6. Works great.. So now what I need to do instead of copying the whole row from the sheet if it matches criteria but instead, copy A9, h2, b9 from source sheet to destination sheet starting at a8 (a9) b8 (h2), c8 (b9). Then do the same for next one that matches criteria and paste it into a9.. etc until end loop.

Comment: @Vince I edited my answer. Mark it as answered if that fixed your problem. Then you can open another question and I or someone else can look at it.